# Storage issue in core data _NSFaultingMutableSet while storing relations

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a modal,

xsdContact (NSString name, xsdListOfAddresses ListOfAddresses)
xsdListOfAddresses (NSMutableArray ContactAddress (xsdContactAddress objects))
xsdContactAddress (NSString city)

I have created Entity as follows
xsdContact (NSString name, relationship ListOfAddresses too many of type or destination xsdContactAddress)

Here it comes the issues, when i try to add object
[xsdContactObject addListOfAddressesObject: xsdContactAddressObject];
it is not adding. it shows _NSFaultingMutableSet when debug.

I understand that since in modal class of  xsdContact ListOfAddresses has  xsdListOfAddresses type, it shows _NSFaultingMutableSet.

Please let me know the solution, one thing i cannot change the definition of modal class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by a hack.

I have added a new Relationship attribute with different name and used it to store and relationship data

for eg:

I have renamed xsdContact ListOfAddresses to Address, since core data internally created the new attribute relation named Address. It was not required me to update the modal and the existing functionality if ListOfAddresses was not changed